# Show (print) featured image all dimensions (height, width)

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

```
<a class="classname" href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>">Full Image</a>
```

Im using this code:
Output is text "Full Image" linked to the post url of the full featured image.
What I want to achieve is to add dimensions to show for that image as f.e:

"Full Image 600x400" or Only "(600x400)"

Thanks!

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_src` allows you to retrieve this information. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your functions.php file:

```
function show($size = NULL) {
    global $post;
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    if(isset($size)){
        $image_data_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id,$size);
    }else{
        $image_data_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id);//Default value: 'thumbnail'
    }
    echo $image_data_array[1]."x".$image_data_array[2];//here you can add more chars of strings if you want
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<a class="classname" href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>">Full Image <?php show('full'); ?></a>
```

this is outputting `WidthxHeight`, you can use any default image size `thumbnail, medium, medium_large, large, full` or any custom size you have added using [add_image_size()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)